# Query a DataFrame with another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a main `DataFrame` by values in multiple columns and rows of a second `DataFrame`. We could say the second is the *search condition*.

The initial data looks like this

```
   a  b  c
0  A  0  b
1  A  1  b
2  A  2  b
3  B  3  a
4  B  4  x
```

I want to filter/search for all rows where `a=='B'` and `c=='a' | c=='x'`. This can be represented as a `DataFrame`.

```
search_for = df.loc[:, ['a', 'c']].iloc[3:5]

   a  c
3  B  a
4  B  x
```

The point is that I do not know the concret search values because they are a result of another "query" and stored in a DataFrame.

It can be done like this and the result is correct.

```
search_for = df.loc[:, ['a', 'c']].iloc[3:5]
query_mask = (df.a.isin(search_for.a) & df.c.isin(search_for.c))
result_a = df[query_mask]
```

But because I have much more then just two columns in the real data I would prefer something like this Pseudocode:

```
df[search_for]
```

Here es an **approach** which does not fully work.

```
search_for = df.loc[:, ['a', 'c']].iloc[3:5]
query_mask = df.loc[:, search_for.columns].isin(search_for)
result_b = df[query_mask]
```

Result is

```
     a   b    c
0  NaN NaN  NaN
1  NaN NaN  NaN
2  NaN NaN  NaN
3    B NaN    a
4    B NaN    x
```

This is the full MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)

# initial data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': list('AAABB'),
    'b': range(5),
    'c': list('bbbax')
})
print(f'\nPrimary data:\n{df}')

# the values I need to search for
search_for = df.loc[:, ['a', 'c']].iloc[3:5]
print(f'\nSearch for:\n{search_for}')

# IMHO bad solution
result_a = df[df.a.isin(search_for.a) & df.c.isin(search_for.c)]
print(f'Result-A\n{result_a}')  # correct result

# An approach not fully working
search_for = df.loc[:, ['a', 'c']].iloc[3:5]
query_mask = df.loc[:, search_for.columns].isin(search_for)
result_b = df[query_mask]
print(f'Result-B\n{result_b}')
```

The full MWE output

```
1.2.5

Primary data:
   a  b  c
0  A  0  b
1  A  1  b
2  A  2  b
3  B  3  a
4  B  4  x

Search for:
   a  c
3  B  a
4  B  x
Result-A
   a  b  c
3  B  3  a
4  B  4  x
Result-B
     a   b    c
0  NaN NaN  NaN
1  NaN NaN  NaN
2  NaN NaN  NaN
3    B NaN    a
4    B NaN    x
```

Comment: what about merge like `df.merge(search_for)[search_for.columns]`?

Comment: This is the correct answer. You should just merge

Comment: It is the solution. But I do not understand why you do not post this as an answer? I can do this for you but then I receive the credits and reputation points for it. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas way would be to use `DataFrame.merge()`.

```
df.merge(search_for)[search_for.columns]
```